# Django UserForm edit no username

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I made a custom user interface for user. I can create the user and *edit* with no problem except that when in edit form, the previous user doesn't show (nor does the passwor1, but that's ok I guess).

I don't know what I'm missing. It's a silly thing maybe, but I want it to be displayed.

The form:

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control',})
        self.fields['password1'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control',})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control',})
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
```

The view:

```
class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm    
    template_name = 'security/user_create.html'
    success_message = "El usuario fue editado exitosamente."
    permission_required = ('user.can_update')

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        person_id = self.kwargs['person_id']
        return reverse('people:person-detail', args = [person_id])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['person'] = Person.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['person_id'])
        context['form_user'] = self.form_class
        return context
```

The template:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            {{ form_user.username }}
        </div>   
   </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be defining or using `form_user`. That's a reference to the form *class*; the *instantiated* form, including the initial data, is already passed to the template as `form`.

Answer (score 0):

UpdateView allows you to just put `{{ form }}` in the template without defining the form in the view.

For the form to work, you are going to need something like this:

`<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>`

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to have control over the html output, so I use the form fields.